# Using Indices Within Loops in R

Tags: r, string, loops, indexing

I would like to change the indexing within a loop based on criteria (the presence or absence of data within each file) when I read in data from a working directory. The data I’m dealing with is a string, hence I'm using `grep`, `grepl`, `regexpr` and `regmatches`. For example purposes, I made it simpler, assume I have two txt files called “`a`” and “`b`”:

```
> a
   V1          V2
1   x           y
2   a 0.833223959
3   b 0.091844199
4   a 0.621608435
5   b 0.777329289
6   a 0.751375338
7   b 0.901111344
8   c  0.21334871
9   a 0.497397497
10  b 0.411770909
11  a 0.231413906
12  b 0.784392324

> b
   V1          V2
1   x           y
2   a 0.599759758
3   b 0.749867176
4   a 0.903613002
5   b 0.463056008
6   a 0.180150744
7   b 0.046976206
8   a 0.209595667
9   b 0.260654739
10  a 0.462145366
11  b 0.707365526
12  b  0.98813125
```

I am storing them in a directory and would like to bulk read them as a string using:

```
txtfiles = list.files(pattern="^[^.].*\\.txt$")
```

I would then like to select the 3rd occurrence of the numeric value after “a” with the exception of where there is a “c” in the data file – in which case, I would like to select the numeric value after the 4th occurrence. My first thought was to do include the indexing with a letter instead of a number i.e. `[d]` instead of `[3]`, which works where:

```
txtfiles = list.files(pattern="^[^.].*\\.txt$")
d<-3
for (i in 1:length(txtfiles)){
    all_data <- readLines(txtfiles[i])
    temp <- all_data[a2 <- grep("a",all_data)] [d]
    a1[i] <- regmatches(temp, regexpr("[0-9]{1,9}.[0-9]{1,9}",temp))

}
```

When I want to change the value of d based on the occurrence of “`c`” in the file, it seems to work:

```
for (i in 1:length(txtfiles)){
all_data <- readLines(txtfiles[i])
temp <- any(grepl("c", all_data))
d[i] <- ifelse(temp, '4', '3')

}

> d
[1] "4" "3"
```

However, when put it all together in the loop, with the objective of changing the value of “`d`” as above, it doesn’t seem to work:

```
for (i in 1:length(txtfiles)){
    temp <- any(grepl("c", all_data))
    d[i] = ifelse(temp, '4', '3')
    all_data <- readLines(txtfiles[i])
    temp <- all_data[a2 <- grep("a",all_data)] [d[i]]
    a1[i] <- regmatches(temp, regexpr("[0-9]{1,9}.[0-9]{1,9}",temp))

}

> a1
NULL
```

Assistance gratefully received!

Comment: You can debug by going inside the loop. E.g., set `i <- 1`, run each of the five lines, see that the thing to the right of `<-` is what you are expecting in each case.

Comment: By the way, this step is very weird: `all_data[a2 <- grep("a",all_data)]`. Assignments inside `[]` are something I haven't seen before.

Comment: read in the data, select all rows with a *or* c; if there is a c, take the 4th a-row; otherwise, take the 3rd a-row?

Comment: @rawr thanks for your comment, this was a simple example, the actual data is a giant (and variable) string as stated in the post which is why I'm _not_ selecting on a row basis. The data in the files I have is a mixture of arrays and strings, so I am reading it all in as a string.

Comment: is your data in strings because you didn't set `header = TRUE` which is why you have both `V` headers and `x`/`y`  headers?

Comment: @rawr no I'm, purposefully reading it in as strings to be comparable to the actual data I have. With the files I have there is no way to read it in as a data table. My problem isn't really the data format, but the issue with how to change the value of the index within the loop.

Comment: can you `dput(a)` and `dput(b)` instead then. just a small sample of the real data

Comment: Dry Gas Flow Rate:    2.6270 MMSCF/day
             Glycol Losses with Dry Gas:    0.0345 lb/hr
                  Wet Gas Water Content: Saturated
       Calculated Wet Gas Water Content:    131.43 lbs. H2O/MMSCF
   Calculated Lean Glycol Recirc. Ratio:      2.84 gal/lb H2O

                                      Remaining   Absorbed  
                Component             in Dry Gas  in Glycol 
     ------------------------------- ----------- -----------
                               Water       5.31%      94.69%
                      Carbon Dioxide      99.80%       0.20%

Comment: @rawr so you see, the data is messy, which is why I was reading it in as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this:

```
if (temp==FALSE)
{ d <- 3 

} else
{ d<-4 
}
```

Is required instead of the:

```
d[i] = ifelse(temp, '4', '3')
```

This is because the above gets a list of all permutations of `d` for all cases. In actual fact, I needed `d` to change with each run of the loop, so that the index will change with each file.

Additionally, `d` does not need an `[i]`.